# How to parse different date strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm stuck on a question. How to convert the date strings:

```
["2010/03/30", "15/12/2016", "11-15-2012", "20130720"]
```

to:

```
["20100330", "20161215", "20121215", "20130720"]
```

Comment: Shouldn't `2016215` be `20161215`?

Comment: What does `11-15-2012, 20130720` represent?

Comment: updated question

Comment: There’s a million questions here about formatting dates in Ruby; did none of them provide you with any insight into this question? Have you made any attempt at all to solve this on your own that you can show us with code? There’s a big difference between “do my work for me” and “I want to do X but when I tried Y I got Z. How do I do X?”

Answer (score 1):

Most can be parsed with [`Date.parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse). But it doesn't understand all of them.

```
2.4.4 :013 > Date.parse("11-15-2012")
ArgumentError: invalid date
    from (irb):13:in `parse'
    from (irb):13
    from /Users/schwern/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

For any that it doesn't understand you can rescue from the ArgumentError and try your own parsing with [strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime).

```
require 'date'

def parse_date(date)
  Date.parse(date)
rescue ArgumentError
  Date.strptime(date, '%m-%d-%Y')
end

dates = ["2010/03/30", "15/12/2016", "11-15-2012", "20130720"]
puts dates.map { |date| parse_date(date) }
```

Comment: `Date.parse` "I question whether `parse` should ever be used, considering how it may lead to some very strange results". `#=> #<Date: 2019-05-01 ((2458605j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`. If the date may be one of several formats wouldn't it be better to use `strptime` with multiple format strings? Another: `Date.parse` "Where is 007 when you really need him?"
 `#=> #<Date: 2019-01-07 ((2458491j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I agree, if the set of possible formats is known. Perhaps varous strptimes with a parse fallback.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
dates = ["2010/03/30", "15/12/2016", "11-15-2012", "20130720"]
dates = dates.map{|date| date.tr("/-","")} # runs through every string in the array and replaces the stuff
```